# str_pad retornando valor vazio

Tags: php

criei uma função com str_pad para meu site, porém ela está me retornando um valor em branco alguem poderia me dar uma ajuda?

```
    function ret($valor, $tamanho, $orienta){
        if($orienta == 0){
            str_pad($valor, $tamanho, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        else{
            str_pad($valor, $tamanho, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        }
$teste = ret("37250468", 14, 0);
echo $teste;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente o código abaixo, acho que apenas faltou você retornar os valores:

```
    <?php

    function ret($valor, $tamanho, $orienta) {
      if ($orienta == 0){
          return str_pad($valor, $tamanho, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
      }
      else {
          return str_pad($valor, $tamanho, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
      }
    }

    $teste = ret("37250468", 14, 0);
    echo $teste;
```

Comment: Olá amigo... perfeito era isso mesmo... rsrs

Comment: Olá, que bom! Se utilizou a resposta, selecione-a como a resposta correta para que outras pessoas que tiveram o mesmo problema vejam como resolver. Obrigado.

Comment: @guastallaigor um dia ele responderá como certa. rs